# View git commits locally with graphics

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and am using github for my remote rep. Is there a way to view all local commits and branches through a chart like when you view it in the github *Network Graph Visualizer*? More like a localhost version of github except it's for viewing commits (instead of using `git log`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the gitk history viewer. I believe it is provided by default with most installations of git. Simply type:

```
$ gitk
```

While the interface may appear slightly dated, it is completely functional.

**NB**: By default it will only show you the commit graph leading to the *current* branch/commit you are on. If you want to see the graph for *all* branches (as your question suggests, and as in GitHub's Insights-->Network view), you need to run `gitk --all`.

See the [ProGit online book section on graphical interfaces](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Git-in-Other-Environments-Graphical-Interfaces) for this and more details.

Answer (score 3):

`$ git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative`

It's really neat, the only difference it shows top to bottom rather then left to right.

run the following command

`git config --global alias.lg "log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative"`

to create a global alias: git lg

You can find all my aliases at https://github.com/orefalo/bash-profiles/blob/master/git-config.sh